# Javascript files not mapping correctly in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue with my javascript files in a master page ... I have the following:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="Scripts/Plugins/jquery-corners.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This works ... until I start to go deeper into the routes ... for example, `http://localhost/mywebsite` works, but `http://localhost/mywebsite/action` does not work - I lose all my javascript imports.

I have use Url.Content for my images ... but it doesn't look like I can do anything for my javascript.  It can't be that difficult ... I must be missing something!  Any help would be appreciated!

**Update**

I found the following [Using scripts in a master page with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347528/using-scripts-in-a-master-page-with-asp-net-mvc) ... but I can't get this to work if I put it between the  tags ... where I need it.  If I do try putting it there I get the following error:

> The Controls collection cannot be
>   modified because the control contains
>   code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of other posts here on stackoverflow. Here is what finally worked:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/CreativeLogic.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery-corners.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.part').corner("15px");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @jdigital My bad ... pasted the wrong code in ... you were close ... I just need to use the Url.Content method.

Comment: A workaround of Url.Content can be ResolveUrl.
But Url.Content is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Check out UrlHelper.Content (can't find MSDN docs, sorry)